# pyodbc Syntax Issue 'Too few parameters. Expected 2'

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I have looked at several different similar examples here on Overflow and haven't had any luck finding a solution to my issue.  The offending line appears to be the following:

```
cmd = "'''UPDATE [Python_Test] SET [DB #] = ['123456798'] WHERE Case2 = 
            ['ZZZ00000']'''"
```

I run this using the following command (which 100% works when I do INSERT pyodbc commands):

```
crsr.execute(eval(cmd))
```

As the title implies, I keep getting the following error message:
('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 2. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')

I've seen several times that special characters can cause issues, but I believe I have taken necessary precautions against that type of issue, but maybe someone can see something that I have totally missed.

If anyone needs any follow-up info please feel free to let me know!

Comment: Why are there brackets (`[]`) around `'123456798'` and `'ZZZ00000'`?

Comment: What you are seeing here is roughly my 10th iteration of this code.  I have left the brackets on and off several times just trying to influence some kind of a different outcome, though i know the brackets make no difference for those values.  So to answer your question, it was just me attempting to brute force my way into some type of an answer. Please feel free to ignore them as the outcome doesn't change regardless. Thanks!

Comment: That's not even valid python. The double quotes around the triple single quotes with an embedded linebreak is a SyntaxError. Get rid of the outer double quotes to get rid of the SyntaxError which also removes the need to call `eval(...)`

Comment: Just gave that a shot.  Still had the same result unfortunately.  'Too few parameters. Expected 2'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `[DB #]` is numeric and `[Case2]` is text, try with:

```
cmd = "UPDATE [Python_Test] SET [DB #] = 123456798 WHERE [Case2] = 'ZZZ00000'"
```

Comment: That was indeed the winning suggestion!